# Oozie email action escape tags

Tags: xml, oozie

we have a following oozie email action

```
<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
    <to>some-email</to>
    <subject>some subject Failure</subject>
    <body>
        Error (Code) Message:(${wf:errorCode(wf:lastErrorNode())}) ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
    </body>
</email>
```

The contents of error message have some text like `<init>` . This is causing the oozie email action to fail with following error,

```
JDOMParseException: Error on line 36: The element type \"init\" must be terminated by the matching end-tag \"</init>\".
```

I couldn't able to find a way to escape those characters. any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the body need to be a plain-text (see [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/DG_EmailActionExtension.html))

You can use other [EL functions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.2_Basic_EL_Functions) to do simple xml escaping by using the `replaceAll` or you can encode the body to utf-8.

Comment: thanks for the response. Looks like, this issue was fixed in oozie 4.x client version. In my case the client version is 3.x.I also went down the path to write a custom EL function that would make use of [escapexml](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml10-java.lang.String-) method.